# get values from listview to textbox in another form C#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, textbox, listviewitem

i try to get data row from listview to textbox in another form. in my listview, i only used two columns from database to display data. i use this code :

```
  private void loadStudentList()
    {
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.Columns.Add("ID");
        listView1.Columns.Add("Name");
        listView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
        listView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);

        MySqlConnection conn = ConnectionService.getConnection();
        MySqlDataAdapter ada = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from student", conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ada.Fill(dt);

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];
            ListViewItem listitem = new ListViewItem(dr["id_student"].ToString());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["name"].ToString());
            listView1.Items.Add(listitem);
        }
    }
```

[item in listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmtGZ.png)

if i click or enter an item contained in listview , it will display another form . on the form I want to display a row from my database like id , name, address and email in the textbox. and this code form call another form :

```
    private void listView1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == 13)
        {
            DetailForm ti = new DetailForm();
            ti.Show();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

[like this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDznm.png)

is there any that can provide a solution ? thank you.

Comment: Where do you have address and email stored? Those are not shown in your code? You can either do a new SQL query to get those values, or include them into your datatable and fetch them from there...

Comment: @kyle_engineer email and address are in the table 'student' . inrow with id and name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous solution for this problem. Usually the simplest one is to call the constructor of the second form passing the values you want to use there.
In your case the ID value of the ListView is just enough to build a query (in the second form) to retrieve all the users values

```
private void listView1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == 13)
    {
        if(listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            string studentID = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;
            DetailForm ti = new DetailForm(studentID);
            ti.Show();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the DetailForm should have a constructor that receives the ID passed

```
public class DetailForm : Form
{
     public DetailForm(string studentID)
     {
          InitializeComponent();
          // code that retrieves the student details knowing the studentID
          DataTable dt = GetStudentDetails(studentID);
          // code that sets the DetailForm controls with the student details
          if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
          {
              txtStudentName.Text = dt.Rows[0]["StudentName"].ToString();
              ... and so on ....
          }
          ....
     }
     private DataTable GetStudentDetails(string studentID)
     {
         using(MySqlConnection conn = ConnectionService.getConnection())
         using(MySqlDataAdapter ada = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from student where id_student = @id", conn))
         {
             ada.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = studentID;
             DataTable dt = new DataTable();
             ada.Fill(dt);
             return dt;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, in the DetailForm you receive the studentID extracted from the first form. You don't try to reach the ListVIew but instead execute the ADO.NET command to retrieve data from your database using the studentID received as your primary key for the search.

Comment: thank you for the example you gave . very helpful to me . I 've tried it , but when pressing the enter button appears " FormatException was unhandled " on int idBarang = Convert.ToInt32(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text); . have I missed something ?

Comment: I suppose that student_id is a number. I mean the first column of your listview contains a number?

Comment: in my database have 5 colums of 'number', 'student_id', 'name', 'address' and 'email'. first table is 'number' column, i using type int and auto_increments. my listview only show 2 column of student_id and name.  student_id using type varchar because i want to make student_id with random character.

Comment: Of course the values in the column student_id should be unique (meaning no student has the same student_id equal to another student). If this is the case then we need to change some datatypes on the code above

Comment: Now student_id is treated as string along the various calls. And the parameter added to the DataAdapter is of type text (varchar)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just create a refference instance to your main list view in your child form, which will give you the possibility to make whatever you want with it, which makes it more comfortable IMO :D

In your main form with the list you'll need to put an instance, where you can access your listview from. Just like:

```
public ListView getMyListView
{
    get{return listView1;}
}
```

Then you'll need to pass your main form as a parameter when showing your `DetailForm`. For that you'll need to change the structure of your second form like:
    public DetailForm(MainForm mainForm)

Then, you can create a second listview in your child form which will be refferenced to the listview of the first one:

```
ListView g_lvMainListView; 
public DetailForm(MainForm mainForm)
{
    g_lvMainListView = mainForm.getMyListView;//now you already have a bound lsitview to the main list view
    //etc...
}
```

The last thing you'll need is to call your `DetailForm` like:

```
ti.Show(this);
```

so that you can pass your main form as an argument.

[Edit 1]
This is ofcourse just an example of how to transmit your data between the forms, you can change the code to serve your needs in the most proper way according to what exactly you demand.

Comment: I was under the impression that the ListView doesn't contains all the fields required by the DetailForm. The OP says that he has two columns ID and Name. So allowing the access to the ListView (apart from being bad OOP practice) doesn't solve the problem. But I can be wrong.

Comment: Could be. I'm just suggesting the use of the ListView as an example of how to transmit data between the forms. Ofcourse he can change the code and retrieve what data he needs to access the database and accomplish what he needs. It's up to him, the main point is, that he can know how to pass his data between the forms, which is IMO the point of the topic.